# Visa requirements for exiting CDG and AMS as layover spots

Tags: schengen, turkey, paris, amsterdam

I asked a version of some of these questions in [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175515/trip-to-turkey-stops-in-paris-and-amsterdam) post, but my writing was unclear.

Suppose one has a round trip single itinerary ticket from the US to Turkey and a US passport. There is a daytime stop in CDG on the way there and overnight in AMS on the way back.

### **Question 1:**

Is a visa (whether on entry or exit of either airports) required to be obtained to travel in and out of them  and explore?

### **Question 2:**

Are there any fees involved with traveling in and out of these airports?

### **Question 3:**

Is there anything else I should know?

### What I've referenced

- The official literature on the EU website but it
  isn't immediately clear to me.
- [This](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/175530/130127) answer explains that there are no fees or testing requirement (at least for Paris), but doesn't address whether a visa is required.
- [This](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144133/long-layover-in-amsterdam-airport) answer was linked in regards to AMS but isn't applicable because I don't have a Schengen visa.
- Another possible complication that I don't understand the
  consequences of is that the [rules change](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/us-citizens/) for AMS because the last
  country I would have flown from is Turkey, and not the US, (and it has
  its own set of rules for entry?)

I understand Turkey needs an e-Visa and a health form. This is taken care of.

Comment: US citizen traveling on a US passport does not need a visa for France or the Netherlands.

Comment: What rules change?  Why is the country you're traveling from relevant?  Also, you've linked to an unofficial website. The official one is https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/schengen-borders-and-visa/schengen-visa_en

Comment: Why do you think that flying into AMS from Turkey rather than from the US means the entry rules change?

Comment: @Traveller for Covid rules the country one travelled from was (is?) relevant. But of course not for visa-related rules

Comment: Are all flights in the same ticket? Do you have checked baggage? Do you need to retrieve your checked baggage (for the overnight layover) or in the contrary do you want to avoid handling it (for the daytime layover)? There could be complications in that area…

Comment: This sentence: "On the other hand, US residents coming from countries that have not established a visa-free regime with the EU will have to apply for a Schengen visa in the US, in order to be able to enter any of these countries." @phoog from the unofficial EU site.

Comment: @jcaron All flights are on the same ticket. I do not have checked baggage, so none will need to be retrieved.

Comment: @johnrabbit that sentence is very sloppy.  It applies to people who live in the US who are citizens of other countries.  That's one reason why it's better to stick to official sources.  That site is unfortunately mistaken for an official source far too often.  In addition to sloppy writing, it occasionally has information that is downright incorrect, often because it is out of date.

Comment: wonderful, thanks for the clarification @phoog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, leaving the secure transit zone of CDG or AMS or any other airport in the Schengen Area means you are entering the Schengen Area. The same regulations apply whether your stay is 90 minutes or 90 days.

For your specific questions.

- You are a citizen of USA. You don't need a visa for Paris and Amsterdam. You can get outside and roam around if you want (Which means entering Schengen Area, which requires that you haven't stayed more than 90 days in past 180 days in the Schengen Area.) You may need to show proof that you are fully vaccinated against COVID-19 to enter the Schengen Area.
- The fees involved is already collected as part of your ticket. You don't need to pay anything extra for Paris and Amsterdam.
- The new rule, aka ETIAS doesn't apply to you yet. The system is expected only in late 2023.
- Have a travel insurance to cover the entire trip. (Optional, but highly recommended)
- Make sure you arrive back in the airport with enough time to checkin.

Comment: @chx Feel free to edit the answer if it is not clear.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, and responding to every point. Not to be pedantic, but where is it stated that COVID vaccination is necessary to enter the Schengen area? @AnishSheela

Comment: @johnrabbit - Here - https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/policies/coronavirus/covid-19-travel-into-the-eu/#:~:text=Travellers%20should%20be%20allowed%20to,the%20completion%20of%20that%20series

Comment: In most countries, you might be subjected to quarantine if you are unvaccinated. Its better to carry the proof.

Comment: You don’t need proof of vaccination to enter France, only to enter Netherlands. And there’s no “quarantine”, you’ll just be denied boarding by the airline. If you avoid Netherlands, Germany and Spain (for direct non Schengen flights) you can travel to Europe without having to show any vaccination certificates.